# "as .... than" vs. "as ... as "

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I have come across these two pages: [p1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/twice-as-much-as-than.444077/) [p2](https://hinative.com/questions/5243106).

Whey discuss about the structure : "as ... than".

They are talking about the following sentences:

> 1 Test conducted on babies reveal that baby girls respond almost twice as much to a loud sound than do boys.

> 2 Tests conducted on babies reveal that baby girls respond twice more often to a loud sound than do baby boys.

> 3 Tests conducted on babies reveal that baby girls respond twice more often to a loud sound than baby boys do.

There are some contradictory opinions on these pages and I got confused.

Also in [this page](https://www.ieltsbuddy.com/pie-and-bar-chart.html) it has been written:

> 4 Men were twice as likely to be arrested for drink driving than women, at 26% and 14% respectively.

Which ones of these sentences are correct?
When can I use the structure "as ... than"? Can I totally forget about "as ... than" and always use "as ... as" which seems a safer choice? For example, can we readily substitute "than" with "as" in the above sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no structure in English, "*as...than*". It doesn't exist. So yes, you can forget about it.

Possible structures are "*as...as*" and "*[comparative]...than*".

Comment: "Twice more often" jars as well. (1) Twice as much...as (2) and (3) Twice as often...as OR more often ...than (4) Twice as likely... as.